# QPixmap shows nothing

Tags: python, qpixmap, pyside6, pyqt6

I have an [image](https://ibb.co/hLzfz8f) of 22Mb

Use python 3.10 and PySide6

```
class Example(QWidget):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.im = QPixmap("C:/work/photos/123.JPG") 

    self.label = QLabel()
    self.label.setPixmap(self.im)
    self.label.resize(400, 400)

    self.grid = QGridLayout()
    self.grid.addWidget(self.label, 1, 1)
    self.setLayout(self.grid)

    self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Exif properties:
ExifImageLength 4912
ExifImageWidth  7360

This code work fine for others image but concrete image doesn't show
What the matter is?

I suppose it is something wrong with image or QPixmap bcz the program works fine on other images with less size

Comment: It's probably because you aren't using an absolute path (despite what your comment says). Relative paths are relative to the *current working directory*, which usually won't be the same as the directory that the script is in. There's nothing wrong with the image itself. It display fine when using a valid path with your example code.

Comment: i changed the path to absolute, others images work fine, but the issue still actual with this image...

Comment: I assumed you were using PySide2/PyQt5, which loads the image just fine. But I see from your latest edit that you are actually using PySide6. In future, please make sure you use the correct tags and also run your example in a standard console / command-window so that you can see any Python tracebacks or Qt messages. If you had done that, you would have seen this output: `qt.gui.imageio: QImageIOHandler: Rejecting image as it exceeds the current allocation limit of 128 megabytes`.

Answer (score 2):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72489732/4926757), executing `QImageReader.setAllocationLimit(0)` solves the issue.

The [source code](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/gui/image/qimagereader.cpp?h=dev) shows that the default allocation limit is 128MB:
`int QImageReaderPrivate::maxAlloc = 128; // 128 MB is enough for an 8K 32bpp image`

The required memory allocation size of `123.jpg` is: `7360*4912*4` = `144609280` (about 138MB) - exceeding the 128MB limit.

Executing `QImageReader.setAllocationLimit(0)` disables the 128MB limitation, and solves the issue.

---

Code sample:

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QGridLayout, QLabel
from PySide6.QtGui import QPixmap, QImageReader

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        QImageReader.setAllocationLimit(0)  # Disable allocation limit

        self.im = QPixmap("C:/work/photos/123.JPG")

        self.im = self.im.scaled(400, 400)  # Scale the image to 400x400

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setPixmap(self.im)
        self.label.resize(400, 400)

        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label, 1, 1)
        self.setLayout(self.grid)

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```